# How render .LAZ or .LAS point cloud 3D models in react three fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, 3d-model, las

I have successfully rendered 3D Model with `react-three-fiber`, which is react wrapper for `three.js`, The *.glb*, *.gltf* files examples are in docs so this was ok. I want to do similarly render point cloud in `.laz` format

I tried [LASLoader](https://loaders.gl/modules/las/docs/api-reference/las-loader) which definitely parse this file, but it's result is not equivalent to scene which is just passed in `<primitive object={scene} />` tag

I am also open to know best ways possible to host point cloud in web with events (like onClick etc), capabilities.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the same thing at the moment (with `laz` files) so looking for a way to convert them to gltf and use them that way. Your LASLoader link is helpful thanks.

Comment: What i did was, convert to PCD and use PCDLoader from three js. Worked like charm.

use cloud compare for easy conversion